# Getting specific value out of the JSON response

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get a specific data out of the JSON file and write it to the output file groups.json. Error I am getting is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Code/ApicaAPIRequests/get_groups.py", line 15, in <module>
    new_data = [{"id": x["id"], "name": x["name"]} for x in data["groups"]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Code example without getting nested items:

```py
import requests
import json

url = "***"

response = requests.request("GET", url)

data = response.json()

new_data = [{"id": x["id"], "name": x["name"]} for x in data["groups"]]

with open('groups.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

print(json.dumps(new_data, indent=2))
```

The JSON data is as follows. I need to be able to filter out id with name, then groups and id, name under inside the groups.

```json
[
    {
        "id": 13061,
        "name": "***",
        "rank": 9999999,
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": 13062,
                "name": "***",
                "rank": 9999999,
                "groups": null
            }, {
                "id": 13063,
                "name": "***",
                "rank": 9999999,
                "groups": null
            }, {
                "id": 13064,
                "name": "***",
                "rank": 9999999,
                "groups": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 11139,
```

Would appreciate any advice as I am learning coding and getting my brain melt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `groups` key at top level. `data` is list of dicts. Each dict has `id` and `name`, but also `groups` keys. To access all `id` and `name` in groups you need to iterate over x['groups'] and for each dict again extract `id` and `name`. List comprehension would not do here. you need regular, nested loops or loop and list comprehension, like this:

```
data = response.json()
new_data = []

for item in data:
    new_data.append({"id": item["id"], "name": item["name"]}) # remove this, if you want just the groups
    groups = [{"id": gr["id"], "name": gr["name"]} for gr in item["groups"]]
    new_data.extend(groups)
```

Note, I don't know the data, so it is possible that there are duplicate values in `new_data`.

If you want just the groups, this will do too

```
new_data = [{"id": x["id"], "name": x["name"]} for item in data for x in item["groups"]]
```

Comment: Thanks @buran. This helped me a lot. :)